# Is it a good idea to build a heavy database (datastore) activity website a good idea using gwt + appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, backend

Me and my friends are planning on building a heavy database activity + heavy amount of dynamically created and stored html pages type of website in appengine. I was hoping to build the front end using gwt and the backend using java in appengine. Initially I was planning to build the backend using php and mysql but due to lack of documentation of connecting php with gwt, I decided not to proceed with that. Would a website like stackoverflow be a good idea to build on appengine? If not, then why? What are my alternatives if I absolutely want to use GWT for front-end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you shouldn't worry about GWT. GWT as a frontend tool won't affect your performance.
The think that you should be careful about is your application design/architect.

Google app engine won't do any magic. It won't automatically make your application scalable. Your application should be designed in a way that can scale well (maybe follow a good stateless design).

That way having your website on google app engine might help you during load picks.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the comment. I guess I'll proceed developing it in appengine keeping scalability in mind =). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is built using GWT - so I guess it can probably handle what you need to do :)

Comment: In fact, Gmail is not written with GWT. It uses Closure Tools (Library).

Comment: Oh ... I must check my sources in future, guess it makes sense, I heard that G+ is closure too.